# Pandas merge fails on large dataframes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm starting with  Pandas 0.17.0, and I can't understand how create my sql query for using  as pd.merge, I created a small dataset, and my test works fine, but with large data the behavior is strange.

My test consist in two files .csv with the following data `file1.csv`

```
id,date,hour,phone_1,phone_2,amount
60000036,08/26/2015,00:17:14,3313268623,445466,1.048
60000036,08/31/2015,05:53:15,3313268623,443316260350,1.048
```

and my `file2.csv`

```
id,date,hour,phone_1,phone_2
60000036,08/31/2015,05:53:12,3313268623,443316260350
```

I run the following commands in ipython (4.0.0)

```
 left = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', low_memory=False)
 right = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', low_memory=False)
 result = pd.merge(left, right, on=['id', 'phone_1','date'], how='left')
# at this point, my output is correct
,id,date,hour_x,phone_1,phone_2_x,amount,hour_y,phone_2_y
0,60000036,08/26/2015,00:17:14,3313268623,445466,1.048,NaN,NaN
1,60000036,08/31/2015,05:53:15,3313268623,443316260350,1.048,05:53:12,443316260350
```

but with large data, the merge fails here my output using large data (two files, 100mb approx):

```
,id,date,hour_x,phone_1,phone_2_x,amount,hour_y,phone_2_y
1313261,60000036,08/26/2015,00:17:14,523313268623,522666,0.048,
1571672,60000036,08/31/2015,05:53:15,523313268623,523316260800,0.048,
```

*Using a large file, the merge always set `hour_y` and `phone_2_y` as NaN, but is not true for all the records.*

In SQL works fine but is too slow:

```
SELECT *
 from calls_a LEFT JOIN calls_b v ON
 v.id = t.id AND v.phone_a = t.phone_a AND v.date = t.date;
```

I can't figure out what happened.

Comment: How does the merge fail exactly?

Comment: Any error or you are getting only two records as output?

Comment: The `hour_y`, and `phone_2_y` always set as NaN when run in large files, but is not true, during my test with small files, The data is merged correctly, Pandas merges if the id, phone_1 and date are equals in both DataFrames, and otherwise it set the columns `hour_y` and `phone_2_y` as `NaN` the output expected.

Comment: Any warning or error message along the way?

Comment: You should rewrite your question as: Pandas merge fails on large dataframes